# need to create same table in hive every hour

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've hive script which runs every hour and has below query in it.

```
create table sometable as select s.*,d.parent, d.key 
    from ${tablename} s join dictionary d 
    where lower(concat(${columnname1},${columnname2})) rlike lower(d.Related_Key);
```

So table needs to be dropped every time manually before running the hive script.

Is there any elegant solution for this?

Hive version used : 0.12.0 CDH 4.6

Comment: I am not clear on your question can you not make truncate table or drop table part of this script?

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a insert overwrite on the table. Something like this

```
insert overwrite table sometable as select s.*,d.parent, d.key 
    from ${tablename} s join dictionary d 
    where lower(concat(${columnname1},${columnname2})) rlike lower(d.Related_Key);
```